# I have Redundant DAO code is there anyway around it?

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

I have several classes (Employee,Customer,Admin) which inherit from a User superclass. I am creating a DAO for each of them but the code for insert remove and delete is very redundant, the only thing different about it is the table names. Is there anyway around this? Also, should each class have its own ID field for the database?

Dao interface below and the implementation following, how would I Generalize implementation to take multiple subclasses?

```
import models.User;
import java.util.List;

public interface IUserDAO {

boolean insertUser(User a);

boolean updateUser(User a);

boolean deleteUser(User a);

boolean verifyUser(User a);

}



@Override
public boolean insertUser(User t) {

    boolean updated = false;

    try {
        Connection myConnect = super.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = myConnect.prepareStatement(
                    "insert into User (UserId, name, userName, password, email) values (?,?,?,?)" );
            ps.setInt(1, t.getUserId());
        ps.setString(2, t.getName());
        ps.setString(3, t.getUserName());
        ps.setString(4, t.getPassword());
        ps.setString(4, t.getEmail());
        updated = true;

    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("User insert failed");
    }
    return updated;
}

@Override
public boolean updateUser(User a) {

    boolean updated = false;

    try{
        Connection myConnect = super.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = myConnect.prepareStatement("update User set UserId = ?, name = ?,email = ?, userName = ?, password = ?");
        ps.setInt(1,a.getUserId());
        ps.setString(2, a.getName());
        ps.setString(3, a.getUserName());
        ps.setString(4, a.getPassword());
        ps.setString(5, a.getEmail());
        ps.executeQuery();
        updated = true;

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("User update failed");
    }

    return updated;
}


@Override
public boolean deleteUser(User a) {
    boolean updated = false;

    try{
        Connection myConnect = super.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = myConnect.prepareStatement("delete from User where id =?");
        ps.setInt(1,a.getUserId());
        ps.executeQuery();
        updated = true;

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("User delete failed");
    }

    return updated;
}
```

Comment: You could also make the DAOs inherit from a common superclass.

Comment: My problem conceptualizing how to have a generic insert function with prepared statements for each of the classes.

Comment: This question would probably be easier to answer if you include code examples in the question.

Comment: Ok will do now.

Comment: sorry, it's still not clear, because with only one example (which is incomplete and doesn't compile) we can't see the redundancy. At first glance, I would say make a `getTableName()` method that is overridden in other DAOs, assuming that everything else is the same. Another possibility is that you could put them all in one table and distinguish the subclasses using a "role" field. Another option is that these different  user  types shouldn't be subclasses at all, instead having one `User` class with `role` as an `enum`. Can a user ever change roles or have more than one?

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement UserDAO class from IUserDAO interface
2. Then override those methods in UserDAO class
3. Then extend the UserDAO class from the subclasses like EmployeeUserDAO ,CustomerUserDAO ,AdminUserDAO

Then you can use those methods without reimplementing them in subclasses with create objects like follow

```
IUserDAO Employee = new EmployeeUserDAO()
IUserDAO Customer = new CustomerUserDAO()
IUserDAO Admin = new AdminUserDAO()
```

Comment: Thanks you so much I ended up implementing my DAO this way. Much appreciated friend!!

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that a generic DAO was not going to be feasible for the functionality I wanted to add so I created 2 separate interfaces for each of the model classes in my program and implemented them fairly similarly as follows.

```
public interface IUserDAO {

boolean insert(User a);

boolean update(User a);

boolean delete(User a);

}


public interface ICustomerDAO {

boolean insert(Customer a);

boolean update(Customer a);

boolean delete(Customer a);

}
```